# How do i close an opened port in Windows 7?

Tags: java, windows

when i try to start my java based server there is a message that says the port is already in use... 
And all my java web servers are stopped... So if anyone can help me i will appreciate it...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If there is really still a process that has the port open, you can easily check for that (and close the process) via [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx). It might be that the port is just lingering (for example due to not being shutdown properly), in which case you'd have to wait for the socket to close and check that the code is clear with regard to that.

Answer (score 5):

I was trying to establish socket communication between **PC**(*JAVA Server*)<-->**Android**(*Client*)
on Debugging, popped the problem : `Address already in use`
*instant/feasible resolution* i found out was to:

> - run **cmd** as *adminstrator*
> - **netstat -abn**
> - find the process listening to the port of intrest
> - terminate the process from **task manager**

---

*PS : Unlike from an external application mentioned in previous answers, steps in this answer allows you to find out the used ports with the resources already present.*

Answer (score 3):

A few options... us [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) to find the program that has the port open and kill it... reboot... just reset the network connection.  Try those.