# localhost:3000 is not working in the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, npm

Backend: Express server, with npx create-express-api backend

Frontend: Next.js, with npx create-react-app frontend

I have implemented these command in my root folder and trying to run npm start xxx to check if they are still working or not. But they are not working in my http://localhost:3000
Though they are working in this link http://172.27.178.192:3000 (on my network)
[This is the image showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axdOo.png)

I have changed browsers and still the same problem is appearing. On the browser it says
Unable to connect
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost:3000.

Comment: Did you check if it works on other browsers like Chrome?

Comment: Yes, I also tried in chrome. Its the same with chrome

Comment: Perhaps you have some entries in the `hosts` file that break the usual behavior

Comment: Should I cange the hosts file? How should I change it

Comment: Is this being run in a virtual machine or directly? If in a virtual machine `localhost` will only work within the machine.

Comment: @PatrickEvans It is being run directly

Comment: @HassanMahmud, Here are about host files:
- Window `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`
- Linux `/etc/hosts`

Answer (score 5):

```
netstat -ano | findstr :8080
```

Then the PID will appear at the right which you can kill with `taskkill`.

The last number the pid.
[image]

then:

```
taskkill/pid 11704 /F
```

[How to close TCP and UDP ports via windows command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688949/how-to-close-tcp-and-udp-ports-via-windows-command-line)

Comment: Which code editor or IDE use? My experinece about visual studio code sometimes stuck. I search the problem but not found. After reinstalled work evertyhing fine.

Comment: I think wort it try reinstall. Yet happpened me that not find a file the correct path because  behind the scenes visual studio code spolied this file reference(after file was renamed)

Comment: Thanks for the msg. Tried it by reinstalling. Didn't work. I don't know, its just if there is any problem somewhere and I can't even find it. Kind of frustrating to be a newbie (•‿•)

Answer (score 2):

I think some other application occupied your 3000 port. try find which one is. If you have found then closed and try again.

For instance you want to free the port 3000 Then, follow these commands.

netstat -ano
taskkill /f /im [PID of the port 3000 got from previous command]

[How to close TCP and UDP ports via windows command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688949/how-to-close-tcp-and-udp-ports-via-windows-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

1. in browser history search for **localhost:3000** and **delete** all of them.
2. make sure you closed all terminalls(check vscode too) and all tabs in your browsers.
3. in new widnows terminal `npx kill-port 3000` do it in WSL2 terminall too.
4. make sure your firewall is turn of.
5. restart you computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have this problem and none of the above helps. Try my solution.
I used http-proxy-middleware and deleted setupProxy.js -> npm start -> restore proxy, and it worked like a champ.

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me

1. Delete the .next folder ( if your working on nextjs ) and try npm run dev command **OR**
2. Move the project to another folder location **OR**
3. Take back up of the code and delete the project and then run the same project again
4. You can try all of the above also