# Development server is not started in Next.js app

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to run the next.js app using `npm run dev`. But the development server is not started. I have latest node version in my system. It is any issues in VS Code.

I attached the photo of when i run the app.

[image]

Here is package.json file.

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@next/font": "13.1.1",
    "next": "13.1.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0"
  }
}
```

OS: macOS Catalina (Version 10.15)

Any Suggestions or advice.

Thank You.

Comment: Do you press anything on your keyboard after "npm run dev"?

Comment: No, I run only command.

Comment: What's your node version?

Comment: Node version: v16.15.0

Comment: Have you tried opening localhost:3000 on your browser and check the console for any error messages? Can you show us the "scripts" section of your package.json file?

Comment: Yes I tried to opening localhost:3000 but they does not show any error in console. I updated package.json file in question.

Comment: Delete your node modules and package lock file and try again.

Comment: @Jeremy, I tried to everything and also create the new project but still not resolve. Any OS issues?

Comment: @Vicky you can see its running, so i'd suggest checking running different solutions on SO, like this maybe. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65438527/11561000

Comment: @Jeremy, The main issues is development server is not started and not issues in localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what exactly the issue is - but looks like it's related to the macOS Catalina and Next version 13.
I have the same issue on this OS, if you will switch to the Next version 12 (this is worked for me) it should be resolved, or you need to upgrade your system.
(Also you could try with Node 18...)